# NIO Java How to make sync Client an async Client?

Tags: java, asynchronous, client, nio

I have an sync Client, how to make this async Client? Client connects properly then it writes to channel, and then it waits (no keys ready because there is nothing to read from channel), now I want it to start writing to channel again, how to achieve this ? Thanks

```
public class Client {
    static class SocketTest implements Runnable {


        private Selector selector;
        private int sessionID = 0;

        int port;
        String address;
        private List<Message> dummyTypeOneResults = new LinkedList<Message>();
        private List<Message> dummyTypeTwoResults = new LinkedList<Message>();

        public SocketTest(String address, int port){
            this.port = port;
            this.address = address;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SocketChannel channel;
            try {
                selector = Selector.open();
                channel = SocketChannel.open();
                channel.configureBlocking(false);

                channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
                channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(this.address,this.port));

                while (!Thread.interrupted()){

                    selector.selectNow();

                    Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();


                    while (keys.hasNext()){
                        SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                        keys.remove();

                        if (!key.isValid()) continue;

                        if (key.isConnectable()){

                            connect(key);
                        }
                        if (key.isWritable()){

                            if(sessionID > 200000){
                                //force disconnect
                                System.out.println("sessionID reached limit forcing disconnet");
                                key.cancel();

                                //call calculate
                                calculate();
                                close();
                                return;

                                } else {
                                write(key);
                            }
                        }
                        if (key.isReadable()){
                            read(key);
                        }
                    }
                }
                } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                close();
            }
        }

        private void calculate() throws IOException{

            //open file


            File file = new File("results_nio.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            FileWriter fw = null;

            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            long totalDifferenceSum = 0;
            long messageCount = 0;
            for (Message message : dummyTypeOneResults) {
                long diff = message.getProcessed() - message.getDispatched();
                String out = "message with ID: "+message.getSessionID()+"  Trip time in seconds %f %n ";
                System.out.format(out,diff/1000000000.0);
                bw.write(String.format(out,diff/1000000000.0));
                totalDifferenceSum +=diff;
                messageCount++;
            }
            for (Message message : dummyTypeTwoResults) {
                long diff = message.getProcessed() - message.getDispatched();
                String out = "message with ID: "+message.getSessionID()+"  Trip time in seconds %f %n ";
                System.out.format(out,diff/1000000000.0);
                bw.write(String.format(out,diff/1000000000.0));
                totalDifferenceSum +=diff;
                messageCount++;
            }
            String totalString = "Total round trip time in seconds %f %n  ";
            System.out.format(totalString,totalDifferenceSum/1000000000.0);
            bw.write(String.format(totalString,totalDifferenceSum/1000000000.0));
            double average = messageCount > 0 ? (double)totalDifferenceSum/messageCount : 0;
            String averageString = "Average trip time in seconds %f %n  ";
            System.out.format(averageString,average/1000000000.0);
            bw.write(String.format(averageString,average/1000000000.0));
            bw.close();
        }

        private void close(){
            try {
                selector.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }

        private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

            int length;
            try {
                length = channel.read(readBuffer);
                System.out.println("Bytes read from server: "+length);
                if(length != -1){
                    byte[] bytes;
                    readBuffer.flip();
                    bytes = new byte[readBuffer.remaining()];
                    readBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                    //create Message
                    ByteBuffer prepareBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
                    int type = prepareBuffer.getInt();
                    int sessionID = prepareBuffer.getInt();
                    long dispatched = prepareBuffer.getLong();

                    Message message = new Message(sessionID, type, dispatched, bytes);
                    message.setProcessed(System.nanoTime());


                    if(type == Message.DUMMY_ONE){
                        dummyTypeOneResults.add(message);
                        } else if (type == Message.DUMMY_TWO) {
                        dummyTypeTwoResults.add(message);
                    }


                }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Reading problem, closing connection");
                key.cancel();
                channel.close();
                return;
            }
            if (length == -1) {
                System.out.println("Nothing was read from server");
                //channel.close();
                key.cancel();
                System.out.println("Send againg new message ");
                key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
                return;
            }
            readBuffer.flip();
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            readBuffer.get(buff, 0, length);

            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
            readBuffer.clear();

        }

        private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {

            //Message format |typeID|sessionID|startTime

            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            ByteBuffer message = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);

            if(sessionID % 2 == 0){
                message.putInt(Message.DUMMY_ONE);
                } else {
                message.putInt(Message.DUMMY_TWO);
            }
            message.putInt(sessionID);
            message.putLong(System.nanoTime());
            sessionID++;

            message.flip();
            int bytesWritten = channel.write(message);
            System.out.println("client write(): bytesWritten :"+bytesWritten);


            // lets get ready to read.
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);

        }

        private void connect(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            if (channel.isConnectionPending()){
                boolean finished = channel.finishConnect();
            if (!finished) {
                key.cancel();
            }
            }
            channel.configureBlocking(false);
            channel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_WRITE); // \p was
            //          channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int DEFAULT_PORT = 9090;
        String IP = "127.0.0.1";

        if(args.length > 1){
            if(args[0]!=null){
                IP=args[0];
            }
            if(args[1]!=null){
                DEFAULT_PORT=Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
            }

        }

        new Thread(new SocketTest(IP,DEFAULT_PORT)).start();

    }
```

//and Message class

```
public class Message implements Serializable  {

    public static final int DUMMY_ONE = 1;
    public static final int DUMMY_TWO = 2;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -555511105603152223L;

    // could be message header
    protected int sessionID;
    protected int type;
    protected long created = System.currentTimeMillis();
    protected long dispatched;
    protected long processed;
    protected Object payload;

    public Message(int sessionID, int type, long dispatched) {
    super();
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    this.type = type;
    this.dispatched = dispatched;
    }

    public Message(int sessionID, int type, long dispatched, Object payload) {
    super();
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    this.type = type;
    this.dispatched = dispatched;
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public int getSessionID() {
    return sessionID;
    }

    public void setSessionID(int sessionID) {
     this.sessionID = sessionID;
    }

    public int getType() {
     return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
     this.type = type;
    }

    public long getCreated() {
     return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(long created) {
     this.created = created;
    }

    public long getDispatched() {
     return dispatched;
    }

    public void setDispatched(long dispatched) {
     this.dispatched = dispatched;
    }

public long getProcessed() {
     return processed;
}

public void setProcessed(long processed) {
     this.processed = processed;
}

    public Object getPayload() {
    return payload;
    }

public void setPayload(Object payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Message [sessionID=" + sessionID + ", type=" + type
            + ", created=" + created + ", dispatched=" + dispatched + "]";
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (created ^ (created >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + (int) (dispatched ^ (dispatched >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + ((payload == null) ? 0 : payload.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + (int) (processed ^ (processed >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + sessionID;
    result = prime * result + type;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Message other = (Message) obj;
    if (created != other.created)
        return false;
    if (dispatched != other.dispatched)
        return false;
    if (payload == null) {
        if (other.payload != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!payload.equals(other.payload))
        return false;
    if (processed != other.processed)
        return false;
    if (sessionID != other.sessionID)
        return false;
    if (type != other.type)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't print 'I am connected to the server' until you've completed the connection; you should count sessions when accepting or connecting, not when a channel becomes writable; the createNewFile() call is redundant; you don't need to clear a brand new ByteBuffer; you don't need two extra steps to get a ByteBuffer from a ByteBuffer; closing a channel cancels the key; you don't need to wakeup a selector running in the same thread; if finishConnect() returns false you shouldn't deregister OP_CONNECT. Please fix the XML escapes. Your code is illegible.

Comment: Thanks EJP for corrections, but still when I do all suggestions my Client is not working asynchronous

Comment: Those were comments not answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between 'asynchronous' and 'non-blocking'.

You are operating in non-blocking mode, but you're blocking in `select().` This is normal.

If you want asynchronous I/O, you need to use an [`AsynchronousSocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html). It is a completely different programming paradigm.

Comment: I don't want to use AsynchronousSocketChannel, I'd like to use SocketChannel and non-blocking mode but somehow to make it work asynchronous. If there is nothing to read from a channel then do write() again. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Ok, maybe I expressed myself in a wrong way. Here is the thing, right now I have this Client, I want to rewrite this code and make that client work in non-blocking mode. I would like that to have a client that continuously writes to a channel if there isn't anything to read. Right now client opens connection ,then key is set to OP_WRITE, then it calls write() it sets key to OP_READ but selector doesn't return any of keys from ready set (even if I use selector.selectNow() instead of selector.select()) . Please correct me if I misunderstood anything and please advise me how to achieve my goal

Comment: If you don't get any selected keys when `OP_READ` is selected, nothing is being received. Check the peer code.

Comment: Yes that's the case, after first write, it is blocked (method keys.hasNext() returns null) till I receive something back, and is there a way I can do write() in the meanwhile ?

Comment: You can write any time you like except while your thread is blocked in select(). I don't understand why you're selecting on OP_READ if the peer isn't sending anything. Is there an application protocol here? Or are you just doing random stuff?

Comment: That's the problem I'm trying to solve. If I don't select OP_READ client should keep writing. But then how to detect if there is something to read. Should I have two separate channels , one for read one for write ?

Comment: I asked you two questions. You haven't answered them.